# Detect roll and pitch ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, accelerometer, pitch

Which way is the best for detecting rolling and pitching? I tried to do with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc]  init];
    self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1/60;

    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:self.queue withHandler:
     ^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
         [(id) self setAcceleration:accelerometerData.acceleration];
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(update) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
     }];
}

- (void)update {
    float accX = atan2f(self.acceleration.x, self.acceleration.z) * 180 /M_PI;
    float accY = atan2f(self.acceleration.y, self.acceleration.z) * 180 /M_PI;

    //convert to 360 degrees
    if (accX < 0) {
        accX = 360 + accX;
    }
    if (accY < 0) {
        accY = 360 + accY;
    }

    NSLog(@"X: %f  Y: %f",accX,accY);
}
```

When the device(iPhone) is on the table, values are X:180 and Y:180 , but when I put device on the right side X is around 90, but Y is chaotic from 0-360.

I would like use it for moving object in 4 directions. It should move like pac-mac, but using accelerometer. When device is in horizontal position, it works ok, but when device is in vertical position, works only in two directions. Is there better way to solve it?